# Casting error in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nullable

I am developing a MVC app. with razor syntax.
I am trying to delete one value from another.

```
  @{
   double DeductedAmount1 = @Model.SanctionedAmount - @Model.DeductionAmount;         
  }
```

This showing error as

Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

> Issue Solved , thanks To Darren Davies

```
dAmount1 = (double)@Model.SanctionedAmount.Value - (double)@Model.DeductionAmount;
```

Comment: You are trying to perform math operation with nullable double. The value may be null here. If so the operation is considered to be invalid. What are the actual types of properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `double?`

```
double? DeductedAmount1 = @Model.SanctionedAmount - @Model.DeductionAmount;
```

Looks like `SanctionedAmount` or `DeductionAmount` are type of `nullable double`

You can also use `.Value` on the `Nullable` double.  For instance if `SanctionedAmount` is of type `double?` and `DeductionAmount` is of type `double` you can do:

```
 double DeductedAmount1 = @Model.SanctionedAmount.Value - @Model.DeductionAmount;
```

Also you can use a `cast`

```
 double DeductedAmount1 = (double)@Model.SanctionedAmount.Value - (double)@Model.DeductionAmount;
```

Comment: @user1650894 use `.Value` - check my edit.  One of your variables is of type `double?` and the other is of type `double`

Answer (score 0):

I would use GetValueOrDefault on your nullable double just in case it is null